# Dropdown menu for recent posts in Blogger

Tags: javascript, jquery, blogger

I am transforming a blog for a friend (applying new template and creating new widgets etc), and since I am a complete newbie with Blogger since I always have used WordPress, he insists on using Blogger and thus I need to make the tough choices.

He had some posts done with his previous template which I have imported into the new template.

He wants me to create a **most recent post** dropdown menu on the navigation bar that opens on hover.

My link is the following:

```
<li><a href='/search/label'>Recent Posts</a></li>
```

But now I have absolutely no idea how to continue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Taz

Harish has made an Ajax Menu like that, you can follow his tutorial from [here](http://www.way2blogging.org/2012/12/new-ajax-navigation-menu-widget-for-blogger.html):

i could include that code straight forward to this answer but i'm not the author of actual code so you have to follow the tutorial.

Comment: @Taz you are welcome. Please mark my answer as accepted (if your problem has been solved) :)